# How do I access the extra attribute on join table in my show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My models look like this:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :contractor_projects
  has_many :contractors, through: :contractor_projects
  validates_presence_of :title, :contract_number, :category, :project_start_date, :project_end_date, :substantial_completion_date, :category, :solicitation_number, :project_officer, :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contractor_projects
end

class Contractor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contractor_projects
  has_many :projects, through: :contractor_projects

  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
 end

class ContractorProject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contractor
  belongs_to :project
end
```

The `ContractorProject` model has an extra attribute #bid_status that I want to reflect on project's show page but it does not appear even though it's in the params when i raised it.

Comment: You can't build your project model with an attribute from an other table in it. In your `ContractorProject` table, each association have an unique `bid_status` ?

Comment: Could you please share the show view and the controller?

Answer (score 0):

below is sample method for your case

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id]
  @contractors = @project.contractors
end
```

inside show.html.erb, you have to loop it, since it may get more than one records

```
<% @contractors.each do |contractor| %>
  <%= contractor.bid_status %>
<% end %>
```